# Get outstanding amount of purchase and sales order with a certain invoice number from Exact Online with a formula

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

I like to get the outstanding amount of the sales orders and purchase orders with Invantive Control for Exact Online.

Is there also a way to filter these invoices?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the amount for sales orders with the following formula:

```
=I_EOL_AR_OUTSTANDING_INVOICE_AMOUNT()
```

And for purchase orders it is:

```
=I_EOL_AP_OUTSTANDING_INVOICE_AMOUNT()
```

You can filter further by filling in the parameters:

`Division Code`, `AccountCode`, `RefDate`, `EntryNumberFrom`, `EntryNumberTo`, `InvoiceDateFrom`, `InvoiceDateTo`, `DueDateFrom`, `DueDateTo`, `CurrencyCode` and `NumberOfReminders`.

When you filter enough to get to one specific invoice, you get the amount for that invoice.

Otherwise you'll get the sum of all invoices included for a total amount.